# Condition in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-scripting, conditional-statements

I want get [4 file name string] from user and pass these parameters to bash script.
script should copy files in user home directory.

FYI: each file might be exist or not, might be one of them exist or four of them.

What type of condition should I use? `if`, `case`, `elseif`?
Here is my script

> ## !/bin/bash
>
> ```
> for var in "$@" ; do
>     T1=$1
>     T2=$2
>     if [ $T1 = "File1" ]; then
>         cp file1 /home/users
>     else      
>         if [ $T2 = "File2" ]; then
>             cp file2 /home/users
>         ....
>         fi
>     fi 
> done
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`if`, `elif` and `case` are all essentially the same thing, they're conditionals.

The difference is stylistic. Technically you could write entire enterprise programs only using `case`, and not `if` and `elif` or the other way around.

Use whatever you'll find the easiest to understand when you come back to your script in 9 months time and have completely forgotten what it does.

Comment: Hahaha. I'll change the `case` of my `CASE`s :)

Comment: Thank you for descriptions, do you have any suggestion for script?

Comment: I think, looking at your issue, I'd use an `if` rather than a `case`. Might look prettier if you have to come back to it and change how things work. Particularly if your use-case changes, and you want to loop over all the arguments passed to your script.

Comment: try that but it always copy file1 and seems one of them [if] execute!

Comment: I modify code please recheck.

Comment: Your code runs fine for me. What command are you using to run it?